# vb2010 webbrowser automate showsaveasdialog to download html including image files

Tags: vb.net, browser

I want to load a webpage in the webbrowser control in VB2010 and then download the page afterwards. Just like in Internet Explorer when you right-click and select "Save page as" you get the .html file and a folder named files.

here is my code...

```
WebBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog()
```

that code works but it pops up a dialog box which asks for the file name and and save location..

What I want is do it programmatically. I want to set to file name and location automatically without a user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

The code is as follows:

```
WebBrowser1.ShowSaveAsDialog()
Timer1.Enabled = True
```

In the timer event write the following code:

```
SendKeys.Send("AAAAAA")
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")
Timer1.Enabled = False
```

This will save the file automatically.

Comment: it is not working sir... sendkeys does not seemed to work during the apearance of dialog...